# iPhone:How to set background image for tablerow cell?

Tags: iphone

I want to put some background image for TableView row cell. I am using the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

.....................

...................
UIImage * backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"];
    UIColor *backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
    cell.opaque = NO;

cell.contentView.opaque = NO;

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

cell.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

//cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//cell.contentView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

}

But it is not giving the background image properly. Could someone guide me what is the proper ways of setting background image for a tableview row?
Note: I'm also setting background image for my TableView as well using the below code:

```
UIImage * backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tablebackground.png"];
UIColor *backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.myTableView.alpha = 0.9;
self.myTableView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
```

I don't observe any problem for tableview background. Only thing here is, tableview background image is not being static, when scrolling happening, image is also scrolling.

But i want to know first how to set background image for Tableview row cell?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone:How to set background image for tablerow cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903911/iphonehow-to-set-background-image-for-tablerow-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by far the best tutorial I've ever read on UITableView customization:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html